# Unity not liking void

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, void

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    //Declare intager Hunger
    int Hunger;
        Hunger = 100; 
    GUI.Box(new Rect(10,10,100,90), "Stats");


    GUI.Label (Rect (10,40,100,20), GUI.tooltip,GUIContent("Hunger", Hunger));
}
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //Every ten seconds Hunger goes down by one.
    Hunger = Hunger - 1;
    yield WaitForSeconds = 10;
}
};


};
```

This is my code for the UI in my upcoming game Rust and Wood. It is perfect but Unity yells at the void in void Update (). Please help.

Comment: That's hardly perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use yield in a Update() method because it is executed every frame.
Only the Start() method can be declared as coroutine by replacing void with IEnumerator.

try this.

```
public class HungerClass : MonoBehaviour {

    int Hunger = 100;

    IEnumerator Start () 
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //Every ten seconds Hunger goes down by one.
            Hunger = Hunger - 1;
            yield return  new WaitForSeconds(10);   
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect (10,40,100,20), "Hunger = " + Hunger);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help pop me your steam and when Rust and Wood comes out you will get it free.

Comment: an upvote and an accepted answer would do it too. :-)

Comment: yeah, you need to have 15 reputation points for that (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the `void` declaration.

You have an extra `}` on `Start` method and also at the end of the file `};`

Also `int Hunger;` should be outside `Start` method.

**Edit:**
I notice that you are trying to use Coroutines wrong. Replace `void` with `IEnumerator` and use properly `WaitForSeconds` coroutine. Also as @JeanLuc said `Update` method cannot be used as a coroutine. Only `Start` method. So you need to change that too.

So it should be:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    int Hunger;

    void Start () {
        Hunger = 100; 
        GUI.Box(new Rect(10,10,100,90), "Stats");

        GUI.Label (Rect (10,40,100,20), GUI.tooltip,GUIContent("Hunger", Hunger));

        StartCoroutine(TickHunger());
    }

    IEnumerator TickHunger () {
        while(Hunger > 0)
        {
           //Every ten seconds Hunger goes down by one.
           Hunger = Hunger - 1;
           yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: I don't think `IEnumerator Update()` will work, but you definitely should not do it. it will reduce hunger by one for each frame not every 10 seconds.

Comment: @JeanLuc not every frame. yielding `new WaitForSeconds(10)` will delay the the next reduction for 10 seconds right? I am not sure though because I never use `Start` or `Update` methods as coroutines.

Comment: only Start() can be used as coroutine. Update can not be used, the Unity Editor will say "Script error (TestUpdate): Update() can not be a coroutine."

Comment: @JeanLuc yeah, it makes sense. I always start coroutines using `StartCoroutine` method so I did not spot that mistake. Thanks and +1 for your answer below.